# Actions on Google converts spelled numbers into strings

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

In my dialogflow project, I am trying to identify a flight number. Currently I have my flight_number as @sys.integer. When a user says the flight number as 'fourteen forty two', it gets recognized and passed to the webhook correctly as 1442, however if a user says 'one four four two', sometimes it gets converted into strings 'one' 'four' four' 'two' and 4 gets passes to the webhook. Is there a way to make sure that it still is recognized as 1442? Or get some consistent data in the request?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try if you can capture the values using "@sys.number-sequence" System Entity which will return you integer value.

Please refer documentation  [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/system-entities)

Comment: That worked. Both fourteen forty six and one four four six now returned as 1446. Interestingly enough Alexa SDK does not have this kind of problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

Speech recognition for a series of numbers may be difficult to get consistently. You may want to try using a [Regular Expression entity](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/entities-regexp) to better capture the value.

Otherwise, you may want to add extra logic in your webhook to translate a series of named numbers to an integer.